# How to update nested dictionary in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have nested dictionary, so something like this:

```swift
var dict = ["a":["b":"c", "d":["e":"f"]], "f":["b":"g"]] // and more
```

Now if I want to update the value of key a.d.e, how should I do that?

It seems updateValue method only reads key as it is...It doesn't know anything about the nested key.

**Edit:**

While I really want to change the structure of this data to something easier to work with. I can't. This belongs to another class and I am not allow to change the structure, all I can do is to update it.

**Second Edit:**

After some thoughts and read the other question some one point out might be a duplicate, tried recursively updating. I feel this is seriously the worst way to do it because essentially it's creating new dictionaries with a copy of original value and assign it back. I do think it is a waste of space and tbh even recursively calling this I feel is unnecessary.

```
func updateKey(key:[AnyHashable],val:Bool,data:[AnyHashable:Any])->[AnyHashable:Any]{
var keyTemp = key
var tempData = data

if(keyTemp.count==1){
    tempData.updateValue(val, forKey: key[0])
    print(tempData)
    return tempData

}else{
    var firstLayerValue = data[keyTemp[0]] as? [AnyHashable:Any]
    var firstKey = keyTemp.removeFirst()
    var tempResult = updateKey(key: keyTemp, val: val, data: firstLayerValue!)
    tempData.updateValue(tempResult, forKey: firstKey)
    return tempData;
    }
}
```

This returns a copy of what I intend to do, and I have to actually assign it back to the original copy. I really don't like this assigning back and forth thing, what if something went wrong in the middle then I might just end up losing the originally correct data.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: While this is possible, you should strongly avoid this kind of data structure in Swift. It is very awkward to work with. If at all possible, convert this to a struct, which will make this (and many other headaches) go away. There are ways to implement highly dynamic data structures if you have specialized use cases, but complex dictionaries (and especially a dictionary that includes `Any` anywhere) are generally not the right tool. What does your data look like? I believe we can find a better data structure.

Comment: @RobNapier I can't change the dataStructure it's part of somebody else's class. All I can do is to update it.

Comment: @Anna Ouch. I've been there before. Is the structure of the dict always going to be exactly the same every single time? You could create an enum for the various values you need to update, then have a method that takes the enum case as a parameter and just write a switch to handle the various values to update.

Comment: @Adrian This dictionary contains like hundreds of values tho, and it's not always going to be the same dictionary...

Comment: Even if you can't change the structure `in-place` you can always create some `proxy-type` that will parse existing `dictionary` and ship changes back.

Comment: Wow…they've given you a really bad thing… Are the keys and values always strings? Or can the final value types be arbitrary? I have some ideas on how to attack it, but attacking the most general case is hard.

Comment: @RobNapier keys are always strings, final value can be strings, int, boolean. It's actually a type of [AnyHashable:Any]. But Whatever value I am updating, values are always going to be a boolean.

Comment: https://gfycat.com/impossiblesilentaxolotl

Comment: OK; I need to think about this. It's an…interesting problem. (And by that I mean an annoying problem you shouldn't have to face.)

Answer (score 0):

Structs are the way to go. But if you really have to use dictionaries, here is a workaround:

```
var dict: [AnyHashable: Any] =
    ["a": ["b": "c", "d": ["e":"f"]],
     "f": ["b": "g"]]

let newValue = true

if var firstLevel = dict["a"] as? [String : Any],
    var secondLevel = firstLevel["d"] as? [String: Any] {
    secondLevel["e"] = newValue
    firstLevel["d"] = secondLevel
    dict["a"] = firstLevel
}

print(dict)  //[AnyHashable("a"): ["d": ["e": true], "b": "c"], AnyHashable("f"): ["b": "g"]]
```

---

To update a value in a dictionary with multiple levels, you can define a function like so:

```
func update(dictionary dict: inout [AnyHashable: Any], at keys: [AnyHashable], with value: Any) {

    if keys.count < 2 {
        for key in keys { dict[key] = value }
        return
    }

    var levels: [[AnyHashable: Any]] = []

    for key in keys.dropLast() {
        if let lastLevel = levels.last {
            if let currentLevel = lastLevel[key] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {
                levels.append(currentLevel)
            }
            else if lastLevel[key] != nil, levels.count + 1 != keys.count {
                break
            } else { return }
        } else {
            if let firstLevel = dict[keys[0]] as? [AnyHashable : Any] {
                levels.append(firstLevel )
            }
            else { return }
        }
    }

    if levels[levels.indices.last!][keys.last!] != nil {
        levels[levels.indices.last!][keys.last!] = value
    } else { return }

    for index in levels.indices.dropLast().reversed() {
        levels[index][keys[index + 1]] = levels[index + 1]
    }

    dict[keys[0]] = levels[0]
}
```

And use it like so:

```
var dict: [AnyHashable: Any] = ["a": ["b": 1,
                                      "c": ["d": ["e": "f"],
                                            "g": ["h": 1.5]]],
                                "j": ["k": 2]]

update(dictionary: &dict,
       at: ["a", "c", "d", "e"],
       with: true)

dict.forEach { print($0) }
```

Here is the output in the console:

> ```
> (key: AnyHashable("a"), value: [AnyHashable("b"): 1, AnyHashable("c"): [AnyHashable("d"): [AnyHashable("e"): true], AnyHashable("g"): ["h": 1.5]]])
> (key: AnyHashable("j"), value: ["k": 2])
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it

```
dict["a"]?["d"] = ["e": 123]
print(dict)
```

Outputs

> ["f": ["b": "g"], "a": ["b": "c", "d": ["e": 123]]]

Comment: The OP mentioned in the comments that the type of the dictionary is `[AnyHashable:Any]`